# Correlation - Negligible correlation but statistically significant... Do the 2 variables have a significant relationship?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, p-value

I run Pearson correlation for 2 variables and the results say that r = .16, signifying a negligible correlation. However, the p-value is significant p = .05

Do the 2 variables have a significant relationship?

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'significant' in two different ways. The term is a common source of confusion.

p < 0.05 is called *statistically significant* by convention. But p < 0.05 does not necessarily mean that a relationship is *strong* or *practically significant*. The correlation coefficient of 0.16 is telling you that the relationship is weak (and positive).

This is commonly encountered when analysing large datasets. Having a lot of data means that you have more *power*, and so even weak relationships may be statistically significant.

It's worth reading more about what p-values are exactly before you proceed. These threads may be a useful place to start:

[What is the meaning of p values and t values in statistical tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests)

[Practical vs Statistical significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81778/practical-vs-statistical-significance)

Comment: And since "statistically significant" means almost nothing and is often a low bar for correlations to pass, concentrate more on a confidence interval for the correlation using Fisher's $z$-transform.