# What are correlation coefficient strong, moderate and weak ranges of distance and phik correlations?

Tags: correlation

I'm using python to calculate different types of correlations such as Pearson, Spearman, Kendall, Cramer's v, phik and distance correlations for some data results in my research.
I want to know the very strong, strong, moderate and weak ranges for each correlation of these to classify the different correlation results in my research.
I got the ranges for Pearson, Spearman, Kendall, Cramer's v, but I can't find the ranges of distance (dcor in python) and phik.

I used this article to help me in my calculations: https://medium.com/@vatvenger/choosing-the-appropriate-correlation-coefficient-a167a65203ff

I need the very strong, strong, moderate and weak ranges of distance (dcor in python) and phik correlations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! The notions of “strong” and “weak” correlations are murky. Why do you need such words when you have the calculated value?

Comment: Hi Monica and welcome on this site! I agree with @Dave. Thresholds like that are controversial in the first place, and their relevance is very dependent on the context of your research. There are many questions and answers on this website about this general issue (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30118/164936, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/126463/164936 , or https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/432661/164936 for some examples). So you should mention why you need this, otherwise I don't think it's possible to give you a good, precise answer, which is relevant to your specific situation.

Comment: I'm calculating correlations between different metrics in a quantum circuit and I need to distinguish between metrics that are strongly correlated and other ones that are weakly correlated.   @J-J-J

Comment: So calculate the correlations. What’s the problem?

Comment: I need the very strong, strong, moderate, weak  and negligible ranges to classify my data, i.e to say that  x & y have moderate correlation but  x and z are strongly correlated

Comment: You can just say what the correlation values are. The categories are arbitrary for Pearson correlation, anyway.

Comment: Okay, thank you.