# What's the point in studying moderation effects if effect sizes are so small?

Tags: interaction, methodology

.002 is the median and 0.009 is the average moderation effect size in psychology, based on [Aguinis et al. 2005](https://www.hermanaguinis.com/pdf/JAP2005.pdf), Effect Size and Power in Assessing Moderating Effects of Categorical Variables: A 30 Year Review, *J. Applied Psychology, 90* 94-107.

I mean, the effect is so small i can't not figure out how it could be of any interest...and the social world is also full of noise...
I'm looking for ideas and suggestions.

Thanks all in advance

Edit: Thanks for the editing. I'm adding some context:

- Journals : All articles published from 1969 to 1998 in Journal of Applied Psychology (JAP), Personnel Psychology (PP), and Academy of Management Journal (AMJ). These journals were chosen for their methodological rigor and emphasis on theory;
- Inclusion criteria: (a) at least one MMR analysis was included as part of the study, (b) the MMR analysis included a continuous criterion, (c) the MMR analysis included a continuous predictor, and (d) the MMR analysis included a categorical moderator. (NB MMR= Moderated Multiple Regression)
- Final sample: "Computed effect sizes for the 261 MMR analyses for which sample size and predictor– criterion correlations across moderator based subgroups were available. We used X and Y variance information when available and assumed homogeneity of error variance for the MMR analyses for which this information was not available.
  In computing the construct-level effect sizes (i.e., based on error-free measures), we used reliability information when available and a value of .80 when this information was not available.
  In computing power, we used targeted f 2 values ranging from .001 to .35 to include a broad range of what can be considered critical effect sizes in applied psychology and management research and the sample sizes reported in each published study."

2° EDIT: Thank @ all the ppl who have answered and commented. I'm closing the question.

3° Edit: Answered

Thank you all

Comment: I added the full citation and a link. But the paper is behind a paywall. Can you, or someone else who has access, give more details? What journals did they review? What inclusion criteria did they use? How did they combine studies? etc. etc.

Comment: On google scholar no paywall

Comment: Are the effect sizes guaranteed to be positive? If not, could positive and negative values roughly cancel out?

Comment: @Dave From the summary in the linked article, they seem to use Cohen's $f^2$ as an effect size, so it can't be negative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen's_f2

Comment: I can't speak to the "rigor" of these journals, but this is only a subsection of psychology, and an old one at that.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- if you have any other valuable source please share

Comment: IMO this question doesn't have a statistical answer per se. It's a variant of the issue of whether research on small effects is meaningful or valuable. That is, it's not an issue of detecting small effect size via increasing N, but it's a question of whether such a pursuit is meaningful. To me, this is a philosophical question. Or at least, I've never been satisfied by purely statistical approaches to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Most often this is a consequence of not scaling covariates to reasonable quantities, like considering 10 year increments of age. If the issue is bad at the main effect level, it is exponentially worse at the 3-way effect level and so on. For instance, consider modeling age by blood pressure against CVD death risk. A 1 unit difference in the age by blood pressure moderator for a normotensive 50 year may represent an individual with a 1/120 unit higher age or a 1/50 higher BP.
2. Even though a general readership can agree to clinically meaningful scales for univariate statistics (and consequently, their bivariate associations), the interactions are sensitive to their joint distribution, and there's rarely an intuitive dyad of units. Consider the below graphic which shows age vs BP vs CAD. A 20 mmHg difference is objectively a clinically meaningful difference in blood pressure considering a person *of any age*. However, given a person *is of a specific age*, a much smaller mmHg difference of blood pressure may be of similar clinical significance. Given this, one could argue to scale an interaction even larger. Again, the normotensive 50 year old scaling age by 1/10 and BP by 1/20 would have age set to 5 and BP set to 6, the interaction is 30. A 1 unit difference represents an individual with a interaction of 31. Controlling BP, this difference is $1 \frac{2}{3}$ years older, controlling age, this difference is just 4 mmHg higher BP, despite the main effects having 1 unit differences corresponding to 10 more years or 20 mmHg more blood pressure. You can scale the interaction term *even further* if it matters for analyses.
3. Often times, a test of moderation is a kind of sensitivity analysis to assess how reasonable the main analyses (without interaction) are. In the case that a moderator is found to be statistically significant, we have objective evidence that the modeling assumptions of the main model are violated. The effect may be small (due to reasons stated above), but the plot of predicted trends over the whole distribution of covariates may reveal aberrations from linearity that affect inference regardless of the value.

Consider this image which is just as I have described above: one can see the lines of the BP vs age vs CVD mortality risk are very close to parallel. So I would trust that the interaction is not significant at a reasonable alpha level chosen for this sample size, and I can safely present results without an interaction term.

[image]

Comment: The article and OP cites $f^{2}$ which is a proportion of variance, so the first point is moot.

Answer (score 7):

I read the article quickly. While you are correct about the median and mean effect size of moderators (they used $f^2$ as a measure of effect), the main point of the article is that this is biased downward by "numerous design, measurement, and statistical artifacts'' (p. 101, start of discussion) and that researchers need to be more aware of these and make attempts to ameliorate them.

They say that the real size of moderators is much higher. And the first author cites his own textbook on the subject.

Comment: Yes i get it. Kenny here https://bit.ly/3vthg9a
"Cohen (1988) has suggested that f2 effect sizes of 0.02, 0.15, and 0.35 are termed small, medium, and large, respectively.  However, Aguinis, Beaty, Boik, and Pierce (2005) has shown that the average effect size in tests of moderation is only 0.009.  Perhaps a more realistic standard for effect sizes might be 0.005, 0.01, and 0.025 for small, medium, and large, respectively"

Comment: @GT87 For the record, Cohen advised *against* using any standard like that, including the "small/medium/large" he suggested, as the importance of an effect is context-dependent. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30118/practical-significance-especially-with-percents-standard-measure-and-thresho/626004#626004 for more details

Comment: @J-J-J  Yes.  I know.  Everybody says that, my tutor says that, my collegues say that, articles say that, even I say that, but then when you have to ground the sample of an exploratory analysis on some base...there you go. You have to rely on arbitrary thresholds, theoretical and empirical reasoning and common sense. In my case, i made up this question because with any of these common-or-restricted thresholds  for an interaction aXb with continuous predictors i need power (subjects) and money i don't have. But that's another topic. Thank you J-J-J. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @GT87 If you have a resource issue, it's unclear to me how using arbitrary thresholds defined by someone else for another context would help solving it. It's not really better than defining your own arbitrary thresholds. For instance, if the costs of an intervention outweight its benefits (possibly measured by the effect size), saying "actually this effect size of 0.002 is medium, not small" won't change the reality of the unfavourable benefit-cost ratio. (By the way, I take no issue with your English, I'm not a native speaker myself, and I find your posts and comments pretty clear).

Comment: @J-J-J The issue is that I'm proposing a correlational study of exploratory nature, where i look for interaction that are theoretically sound but with little empirical evidence and with no dedicated theory, trying to open up a reasearch line, justifying (to others and to myself) the use of experimental designs and -therefore- fundings.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, i'll add something to what has already been said to answer my own question, building on the excellent job the participants to the discussion have made so far.
The article i refer to is this :

> Murphy, K. R., & Aguinis, H. 2022. Reporting interactions:
> Visualization, effect size, and interpretation. Journal of Management,
> 48(8): 2159–2166

The first citation goes by: "Generally, when interaction effects are small, as is the norm in management and related fields (Aguinis, Beaty, Boik, & Pierce, 2005), their theoretical and practical significance will often be felt by only that subset of the sample that is at or near the extreme values for the moderator"

The second goes by: "Aguinis et al. (2010) argued that in addition to providing information about statistical significance and variance explained, authors should also provide information about the meaning of interactions for theory and practice"

As a phd student in social psychology I strongly endorse these asserts.
Oftentimes interaction parameters are given without useful and appliable information, implications are not explored and interpretations are superficial or not given.

Interactions come in many shapes (e.g.

> Baranger, D. A., Finsaas, M. C., Goldstein, B. L., Vize, C. E.,
> Lynam, D. R., & Olino, T. M. (2023). Tutorial: Power analyses for
> interaction effects in cross-sectional regressions. Advances in
> Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, 6(3),
> 25152459231187531.

) but i want to know **when** the interaction i hypothesized is crucial for the behaviours i want to predict. In other words "At what value of the moderator i have the behavioural effect i am looking for?".